# wx file error when using Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to learn to use the wx packages to make GUI programs in Haskell with the following code:

```
module Main where
import Graphics.UI.WX

gui :: IO ()
gui = do
 f <- frame [text :="Hello World!"]
 staticText f [text :="Some static text"]
 return ()


main :: IO()
main = start gui
```

But when I try to compile this I get the following error:

```
C:\Haskell>ghc -O2 --make gui.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( gui.hs, gui.o )

gui.hs:2:0:
    Bad interface file: C:\temp\wxhaskell-0.11.1.2\lib\imports\Graphics

        mismatched interface file versions (wanted "6103", got "6104")
```

This is after I installed wx from a binary file that is the latest version.
What do I do to make this compile or get wx to work in general?

EDIT: On further inspection it turns out I am using using:

```
C:\Haskell>ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 6.10.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have GHC version 6.10.3 and it seems you've wxHaskell pre-compiled with GHC version 6.10.4. That's the mismatch.

Possibilities:
-downgrade wxHaskell
-upgrade to GHC version 6.10.4

It seems many pre-build packages are in transition from being build in version 6.10.3 to 6.10.4. This is annoying. I think time will resolve these kind of issues?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error message, either [download GHC 6.10.3](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_6_10_3.html), or [build wxHaskell from source](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/WxHaskell/Building) on GHC 6.10.4. The first should be much simpler.

UPDATE: Since you are actually using GHC 6.10.3, you need to download [GHC 6.10.4](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_6_10_4.html).

Comment: Does this mean I have to "downgrade" my GHC?